# How to make delay in calling textchanged event of textbox in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, system.reactive

I have custom control inherited from Textbox.

I want to make delay in calling textchanged event.

```
 Observable.FromEventPattern<TextChangedEventHandler, TextChangedEventArgs>(
                handler => this.TextChanged += handler,
                handler => this.TextChanged -= handler
                ).Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(600))
                      .Where(e =>
                          {
                              var control= e.Sender as TextBox;
                              return control!= null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Text);
                          })

                      .Subscribe(x => Control_TextChanged(x.Sender, x.EventArgs));
```

Problem is it is giving error saying, cannot access Text property as current thread does not have access.

Can someone please advice?

Thanks,
Vishal

Comment: Just a small comment - when using normal events you have to do `var control= e.Sender as TextBox;`, but you're using Rx and lambdas so `this` is still in scope. Your where-clause can be written as `.Where(e => this != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Text))`.

Comment: And why are you calling off to `Control_TextChanged`? That seems to be a backwards step. Just put the code in the `.Subscribe` rather than in `Control_TextChanged`.

Comment: @Enigmativity another small comment :) We don't know if `Control_TextChanged` is called from somewhere else in the code. Or if the function length is 1000 lines. Point being: I think the implicit function call is better

Comment: @supertopi - We just don't know anything about it other than it is external to the current method. I try to use lambdas to encapsulate the code as encapsulation is one of the OO tenets so all things considered equal it's probably a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **ObserveOnDispatcher** extension method and have something like:

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<TextChangedEventHandler, TextChangedEventArgs>(
                    ev => TextChanged += ev,
                    ev => TextChanged -= ev)
                          .Where(t => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text))
                          .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(600))
                          .ObserveOnDispatcher()
                          .Subscribe(e => HandleTextChanged(e.EventArgs));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can observe on UI thread:

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<TextChangedEventHandler, TextChangedEventArgs>(
  handler => this.TextChanged += handler,
  handler => this.TextChanged -= handler)     
     .ObserveOn(DispatcherScheduler.Current)
     .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(600))
     .Where(e =>
          {
              var control= e.Sender as TextBox;
              return control!= null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Text);
          })
     .Subscribe(x => Control_TextChanged(x.Sender, x.EventArgs));
```

Notice the use of `DispatcherScheduler.Current` it's in `System.Reactive.Windows.Threading` namespace in `Rx-WPF` NuGet package.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use `Control.Invoke()` to make changes to UI elements from any thread other than the main UI thread.

```
Where(e =>
    {
     var control= e.Sender as TextBox;

     return control != null 
          && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Dispatcher.Invoke<string>(()=>  control.Text));

     })
```

Comment: where I can use, control.invoke. Could you pls give an example?

Comment: See updated code. Sorry if it's a bit messy. Doing this on my phone.

Comment: Ah the one you are saying is in Windows.Form. I am using WPF

Comment: I've never used WPF, but apparently the equivalent is to call `Dispatcher.Invoke()`  - I have changed the answer accordingly.