# How to optimize performance to filter a collection using StartsWith, OrderBy and GroupBy functions?

Tags: c#, list, linq, group-by, uwp

I have a text box for filtering a collection which is a combination of two lists. Both lists are having a common property on the basis of which i am doing OrderBy and GroupBy.

Before doing these two operations i have to filter each list according to the user input in the text box. For that i am using StartsWith function and after that i am combining both the lists on the basis of common property.

All these operations i am doing on Text Changed event of the text box. I am facing a lot of delay in response and sometimes typing faster causing app crash. I think OrderBy and GroupBy are taking most of the time in filtering.

Here is my code:

```
private void locationsearchboxrecipient_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var recipientFilteredDataByPlaces = new List<Table_Places>();
        var recipientFilteredDataByPersons = new List<Table_People>();

        if (locationsearchboxrecipient.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            cvrbyplace.Source = recipientFilteredDataByPlaces;
            cvrbyperson.Source = recipientFilteredDataByPersons;
            return;
        }

        if (PeopleList != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in PeopleList)
            {
                if (item.FirstName.StartsWith(locationsearchboxrecipient.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || item.AccountNumber.StartsWith(locationsearchboxrecipient.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || item.MiddleName.StartsWith(locationsearchboxrecipient.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || item.LastName.StartsWith(locationsearchboxrecipient.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    item.Icon = "../Assets/user_profile.png";
                    recipientFilteredDataByPersons.Add(item);
                }
            }
            }

        if (PlacesList != null)
        {

            foreach (var item in PlacesList)
            {
                if (item.AccountNumber.StartsWith(locationsearchboxrecipient.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || item.Name.StartsWith(locationsearchboxrecipient.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    item.Icon = "../Assets/ic_location.png";
                    recipientFilteredDataByPlaces.Add(item);
                }
            }

        }

        List<IFirstName> combinePlacePerson = (from x in recipientFilteredDataByPersons select (IFirstName)x).ToList();
        combinePlacePerson.AddRange((from x in recipientFilteredDataByPlaces select (IFirstName)x).ToList());
        cvrbyperson.Source = combinePlacePerson.OrderBy(x => x.FirstName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).GroupBy(x => x.FirstName[0].ToString().ToUpper(), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    }
```

PeopleList and PlacesList are the lists object and contain almost 7k records.
cvrbyperson is the collection view source object of the UI which i am binding to the list.

I would be pretty thankful for your help.

Comment: Have you considered [throttling or debouncing](http://www.rudyhuyn.com/blog/2016/03/01/delay-an-action-debounce-and-throttle/) the event for better perceived responsiveness while typing?

Comment: Also, why use `ToUpper` while comparing strings with `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`?  That is redundant. I would get rid of `ToUpper`, as it is going to create copies of every single string.  That is probably  a large part of your performance problems right there.

Comment: Assuming that your lists are contained in a database, why do this in memory instead of letting the db do the heavy lifting? Your code is never going to be able to this faster than the db optimizer.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Sorry for the late reply but I don't really know where to use throttle function in my existing code.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

***1***. **Try to delay the execution of the filtering**. Executing this logic on every keystroke is unnecessary when they are typed pretty fast, because the current state will discard the old state and the user won't even notice the suggestions. Delaying the filtering with 150ms - 200ms is pretty acceptable (you should tweak it to see what best fits). Check out [throttle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35169500/how-to-make-delay-in-calling-textchanged-event-of-textbox-in-wpf) and [timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33776387/dont-raise-textchanged-while-continuous-typing) solutions.

***2***. **For fast starts-with search you can use prefix trees -> `Trie`**. There are several nugget packages for dotnet. I have used [this](https://github.com/dotnetrdf/vds-common) which is stable. If you create predefined instance of the trie with all of the fields you are interested from the `Person` and `Place` objects like `Name`, `AccountNumber` ... etc it should be pretty fast.